# Do clients have to do anything if my site uses SSL?

Tags: ssl

I've been reading up on SSL. It seems like it has this private and public key system for encryption. How do users get the public key? I don't recall having to do anything when I've gone out to https sites. Is something happening behind the scenes automatically for me? Is my browser going something automatically?

I also noticed through some web providers (GoDaddy for example) you can get an SSL cert. My understanding is that cert providers are supposed to do background on your company to see if you are legit. What if I'm not really a company yet and I'm just some guy who wants to have a website?

Answer (score -1):

No, your clients usually just connect to your site (usually).

Behind the scenes, there are too many things happening, it's something like this:

1. You try to access https://yoursite.com — by typing https, your browser understand that you want an encrypted connection to this server, so before any information (that is, your HTTP request) is sent, you have to establish an encrypted connection between you and your server.

   So your browser probes the webserver on how is it possible for them to communicate, it says hello and send the SSL/TLS versions and ciphers it supports together with some data for opening up a SSL session.
2. The webserver receives the incoming connection and replies with its supported encryption and ciphers, more session data and its **public key** (the certificate file, and possibly the certificates that validate that certificate, also called certificate chain).
3. The client checks the server certificate:

   Is it expired?

   Does the CommonName (and alternatives) match the hostname you are willing to access? (note that the client didn't say which URL it would like to get)

   Is it from a valid issuer? To check this it may go through the other certificates in the certificate chain (certificate A was issued by certificate B that was issued by certificate C...) until it sees a certificate it knows and trusts — this is a certificate that was already installed with your computer or browser.

   You may be prompted by your browser if it thinks the connection is not secure (ask for exceptions or things like that).

   If it agrees to connect with this certificate, then it uses the original certificate (as a public key) to encrypt a newly-generated pre-secret key for encryption.
4. The server receives the pre-secret key, that can only be decrypted by using the **private key** it owns (and should never be shared!!!), and then talks a little more with the client to establish a new and unique master secret.

   This master secret will be used by separately by both client and server to generate and exchange the session keys, which will be used for symmetric encryption (which means each one can encrypt a message to the other).
5. Only now your browser will encrypt the request (all HTTP headers and body, if any) and send it to the server.

So all you need to host a https server is a private key and your certificate (that acts as a public key). In order to your certificate be trusted by web browsers, it needs to be signed by a CA (Certificate Authority) that your browser trusts, and here comes all those commercial options **and a free option as well:**

You can use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) to generate a free, valid and secure SSL certificate — you only need to have access to your website root folder.

---

Please note that your server may also require a specific certificate in your browser (probably a step #3.5), but this is much less usual and you would really need to install it on your browser, those are the Client (SSL) Certificates.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there anything wrong with this answer?